# GAC install issue with InnoSetup

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, inno-setup, gac

Windows 8.1 has by default these .net assemblies installed here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.dll

here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Resources\v4.0_3.0.0.0_es_31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost.Resources.dll

and here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Policy.1.0.Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Policy.1.0.Microsoft.Powershell.ConsoleHost.dll

I would like to install them from my innosetup installer to other Windows 8.1 that has Powershell features removed and the lack of that assemblies.

I've read about the `gacinstall` flag but I'm not sure how I should do it to reproduce the same structure that Windows has by default and also I'm not sure whether I should locate and specifiy an strong name in the `StrongAssemblyName` parameter for those dlls, someone could give an installer example?

Comment: The GAC structure is automatically generated and you don't need to take care of it.

Comment: @Lex Li thanks for comment, but anyways I'm not sure at where directory I should copy my files, in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`, or maybe `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`, or where, I really need a code-example of `[Files]` section with `Source` and `DestDir` parameters (and everything else which could be need like `Flags`) just to know how to treat a single file of those files that I commented to properly install them in GAC. thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is OK to set any target folder such as `{app}` in `[Files]` for the assembly file,

http://odd-staff.blogspot.com/2010/04/well.html

But you need to specify `gacinstall` flag so that Inno Setup takes care of registering it into GAC.

Comment: Ok so I only should expand the file wherever (in `{tmp}` for example) and just setting the `gacinstall` flag it will sends the file into GAc directory and installs it?, then ok but in that example that you've linked it uses an `StrongAssemblyName` parameter which I don't know how to properly retrieve and set all those properties used in that param.

Comment: To get strong assembly name, you can utilize [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net). You can see from this image, that the second line in the right panel is the info you want, https://i0.wp.com/1.bp.blogspot.com/-1LWFU_GWlMQ/UQ35ue8KZ6I/AAAAAAAAAxs/rIlKdGK20pM/s320/ilspy.png?resize=320%2C215